# Excel - two columns - remove duplicate values buy comparing pairs in rows

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2013, simplifying the actual data, suppose you have two columns of data, similar to below:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | D |
| A | C |
| B | C |
| C | B |
| C | A |
| D | A |

My goal is to either filter or remove the duplicate pairs regardless of what column they're in.  My desired output would be as follows:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | D |
| A | C |
| B | C |

So, as you can see, the C-B row was eliminated because the pair exists in the row containing B-C.  Same for the rows containing C-A (A-C) and D-A (A-D).  Data will be in no particular order and it doesn't matter which of the two paired matches are removed.

Solution can be via creating a new table or even using VBA to output a new table.  Whatever is easiest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not a free code writing service, but we'd be happy to help you fix a problem you have with code you have made. What have you tried so far?

Comment: As a starting point, you can use `=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,B2,B$2:B2,A2),COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2))=1,TRUE,FALSE)` to identify the first entry of each combination, with `A` being your *column1* and `B` your *column2*. However, it would rather go for a VBA solution.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, Hi, I'm sorry, I'm not expecting anyone to write code for me, I'm looking for a little direction.  I'm drawing a blank on how I might proceed.

Comment: @Qualia, thank you.  I figured a VBA solution might be the best way to go based on what I'm finding in help.  I'll take a look at your formula suggestion though and see if it'll get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Sort each row horizontally;  then it will be easy to find/delete the duplicates.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld, I tries this multiple ways and just couldn't seem to get it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able get this to work for me, so I thought I'd post my answer hopefully helping someone else.  As I suspected, and Quailia suggested, VBA was the way to go.

Few things changed along the way.  I needed to add an additional column to the table as it was determined that there would be some duplicates that I needed to keep.  The values in the first column now group rows together, so later duplicates are kept.  The values I need to check for duplicate pairs, are in column 2 and 3.

Table1:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | D |
| 01 | A | C |
| 01 | B | C |
| 01 | C | B |
| 01 | C | A |
| 01 | D | A |

Also, I realized I would be dealing with a fixed number of rows, so I didn't have a need to keep changing the size of my array.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatePairs()
    'Checks a 3 column table for rows with duplicate values when column 2 and 3 are swapped, removes duplicates and outputs unique rows to a new table
    Dim aArrayList() As Variant
    Dim bArrayList(1 To 144, 1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim aRowNum As Integer, aColNum As Integer, bRowNum As Integer, bColNum As Integer
    
    aArrayList = Range("Table1")
    
    bRowNum = 1
    'Loop through rows of 1st array
    For aRowNum = 1 To UBound(aArrayList, 1)
        If aRowNum = 1 Then
            bArrayList(1, 1) = aArrayList(1, 1)
            bArrayList(1, 2) = aArrayList(1, 2)
            bArrayList(1, 3) = aArrayList(1, 3)
            'Debug.Print bArrayList(bRowNum, 1) & aArrayList(bRowNum, 2) & bArrayList(aRowNum, 3)
            bRowNum = 2
        ElseIf aRowNum > 1 Then
            'Check if current row in 1st array already exists in 2nd array by comparing values after flipping 2nd and 3rd column values from 1st array
            For i = 1 To bRowNum - 1
                If aArrayList(aRowNum, 1) = bArrayList(i, 1) And aArrayList(aRowNum, 2) = bArrayList(i, 3) And aArrayList(aRowNum, 3) = bArrayList(i, 2) Then
                   'Duplicate pair already exists, move onto next row of 1st array
                    GoTo SKIP
                End If
            Next i
        'No duplicate found, add row from 1st array to 2nd array
                bArrayList(bRowNum, 1) = aArrayList(aRowNum, 1)
                bArrayList(bRowNum, 2) = aArrayList(aRowNum, 2)
                bArrayList(bRowNum, 3) = aArrayList(aRowNum, 3)
                'Debug.Print bArrayList(bRowNum, 1) & bArrayList(bRowNum, 2) & bArrayList(bRowNum, 3)
                bRowNum = bRowNum + 1
SKIP:
        End If
    Next aRowNum

'Write array to new table
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table2").Value = bArrayList()

End Sub
```

Table2:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | D |
| 01 | A | C |
| 01 | B | C |

I'm sure there is an easier, neater way to do the same thing, but as my username implies, I'm still pretty new to this.  Any suggestions that improve or simplify my logic are certainly welcome.

Comment: Here's one way that might be simpler:  Add a helper column with a formula: `=IF(A2>B2, CONCATENATE(A2,B2),CONCATENATE(B2,A2))`.  Then do `RemoveDuplicates` looking only at the helper column.  Finally, delete the helper column.  You can do this on the worksheet or using VBA.